# OS X: Eclipse always asks for workspace on start-up and reinstalls plugins from marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, workspace

I am currently using Eclipse Neon.2 on a Mac-book and what bugs me is, that every time I quit eclipse and reopen it, it asks for a work-space and doesn't remembers the default one (the checkbox is also always unchecked).

The consequence is also, that it always `re-installs` the various plugins (like Window-builder) from the marketplace.

Anyone know a solution to this? Already tried reinstalling.

Comment: I assume you check the "Use this as the defaut and do not ask again".

To me this sounds like you're starting the installer instead of the installed eclipse application. Since I'm on Windows I cannot try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: check the permission of the folder where eclipse is installed, or re-install it in a different location